# Typing generic return data based on multiple + optional consecutive transform functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, return-type

I'm trying to type the return value of multiple consecutive transform functions. While my typing works for the result itself and the first transforming method. The typing doesn't work for the second transform method.

[playground ts link to fiddle around](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgJJzAV2FAvFAhnEAGigHkN1Md8QA%20bKACgEtUMAuKFCgSmzrOAUAsAChRAYwD2cAM6ZgAJ3wyAZpIUBbeglFQoAZWDqIAEwBquADZpoEAB7AIcEzKgAlCMDQK4AFXAQCIbGNIS6sJ7iABZQ9o7OrvAI1MRocADWcJIA7nCh4TCRUaYW1rYOTi7unt5%20AQiFwNH5Inr6EJYQ4sACFLEVCdVePv6QQR1dwC1tRgrl8VVJjdElVjapGVm5NAD0AFT0S0WrZcTLxeZrEDR7O2GtBhPd-QuJiMFzl6dQaZk5eftDu9Zid1hEmhdSjYbndRDQGFI4ComABzDgAb3CehURQ453uej0cmM%20wA-LcOB8IATCTInsAyRTHp1ujSAL68LB0TFiB5zYZwKDotl4Vw8wlQHEQ0EQPHHL7rLFQYmfKGygwghXUpV0lmOLWU%20m9DDs0Rs0QSaRyKD8%20iKZRqTQMcWS3GMAD6uA4cDQGgARhAFJzuUr%20bUoAByKUrLUR0WR6OQq4R8Jsmkq9UMd1%204NC0M1HyRjOx%20MR4tqlMPNPhHY7DXGLXYLA4X5bODEP0YZVRSRoSwmKABouaivhXWTDhZlg8Ph5h56MOFsv0mVx3CuZd61ep%204coA).

```
type Fn<Input = any, Output = any> = (input: Input) => Output

const transform = <
  StoredValue extends ReturnType<Store>,
  Fetch extends Fn<any, unknown>,
  FetchedValue extends ReturnType<Fetch>,
  SelectOutput extends ReturnType<Select>,
  Store extends Fn<FetchedValue, unknown>/* = Fn<FetchedValue, FetchedValue>*/,
  Select extends Fn<StoredValue, unknown>/* = Fn<StoredValue, FetchedValue>*/,
>(config: {
    fetch: Fetch,
    store/*?*/: Store,
    select/*?*/: Select,
  }) => {

  return {} as {
    fetchedValue: FetchedValue,
    storedValue: StoredValue,
    selectedValue: SelectOutput,
  }
}

const ret = transform({
  fetch: (a: number) => {
    return 'fetchedValue' as 'fetchedValue'
  },
  store: (b) => {
    return 'storedValue' as 'storedValue'
  },
  // StoredValue === unknown, but should be 'storedValue'
  select: (input) => {
    return 'selectedValue' as 'selectedValue'
  },
})
```

Comment: You didn't provide the entire implementation of `transform`, so I am not sure, but it seems to me like half of generic arguments are redundant. If you leave only the absolutely necessary ones you get [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wva3Ym) which has the correct types but I'm not sure if it covers all cases you are trying to cover

Comment: Yes, because I was more into the typings. It was not clear to me that by defining the functions and using the variables those variables will be inferred. As you assumed, it does not cover all use cases. Because select and store should be optional methods. You can fiddle [here](https://tsplay.dev/Na4A2w). Is there a good way around function overloading?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDDj8N) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually helps to express types in terms of simple type operations on few [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.

It's more straightforward to express function types in terms of their argument and return types (e.g., turn `I` and `O` into `(i: I) => O`) than to do the reverse (e.g., turn `(i: I) => O` into `I` and `O`), which requires more complicated type operations involving [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).

Given your use cases, the underlying types you care about seem to be:

- the input type to `fetch`, `FI` (maybe)
- the output type of `fetch` and the input type to `store`, `FO`
- the output type of `store` and the input type to `select`, `SV`, and
- the output type of `select`, `SO`.

So that leads me to the following typing for `transform()`:

```
const transform = <FI, FO, SV = FO, SO = FO>(
  config: {
    fetch: (arg: FI) => FO,
    store?: (arg: FO) => SV,
    select?: (args: SV) => SO
  }) => {
  return {} as {
    fetchedValue: FO,
    storedValue: SV,
    selectedValue: SO,
  }
}
```

or possibly just

```
const transform = <FO, SV = FO, SO = FO>(
  config: {
    fetch: (arg: any) => FO,
    store?: (arg: FO) => SV,
    select?: (args: SV) => SO
  }) => {
  return {} as {
    fetchedValue: FO,
    storedValue: SV,
    selectedValue: SO,
  }
}
```

if you don't actually need the input type to `fetch()` anywhere (the example code doesn't use that input type, but your underlying use case might).

---

Note that in order to support the use cases where either `store` or `select` are not passed in and therefore `SV` and/or `SO` cannot be inferred from these arguments, I've given `SV` and `SO` [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `FO`.  I'm not 100% sure that is always what you want to do, so you should double check to make sure it works as desired and adjust accordingly.

Also, I'm not worried about having the compiler verify the type safety of the *implementation* of `transform()`.  Both your version and mine return `{}` and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it is of the proper type.  Having the compiler verify type safety for generic type parameters with default type arguments isn't usually possible, so you'll probably need to use a type assertion or something like it in your actual code as well.

---

Okay, let's make sure it works as you expect:

```
const ret = transform({
  fetch: (a: number) => 'fetchedValue' as const,
  store: (b) => 'storedValue' as const,
  select: (input) => 'selectedValue' as const
})
// const transform: <number, "fetchedValue", "storedValue", "selectedValue">(...
/* const ret: {
    fetchedValue: "fetchedValue";
    storedValue: "storedValue";
    selectedValue: "selectedValue";
} */

const ret2 = transform({
  fetch: (a: number) => 'fetchedValue' as const,
  select: (input) => 'selectedValue' as const
})
// const transform: <number, "fetchedValue", "fetchedValue", "selectedValue">(...
/* const ret2: {
    fetchedValue: "fetchedValue";
    storedValue: "fetchedValue";
    selectedValue: "selectedValue";
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `ret` and `ret2` are correct, and the inferred type arguments for `FI`, `FO`, `SV`, and `SO` match what I think you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBFBOBDSAzE8C2MC8MA8AYgJIA0MBA8mQMoBqO5VM1FDlAfABQCwAUDDFBgUASwDmALhgBvPgIEoAplGAALKZ0TxJ5IgEoc7RiTnzo6RQH4NWnZQPYjdE-zOKANouBRrMTdogpOgcnClMAXxCZU3hlAFd4MBlwmEQIaNcFZTVFABNaRHc4xSlKF3kYc1j8wuKg2nK3T288gqKS5ioIvnC+PiFoGFjYXARkCDRMTllXJRV1P0QpMDiMACNFeCiAcjmcmvbt1PSBqEaqjs41nYuD4qO0wXBoc48vKA0RMAAHOKgbt4tO6KB4nZ5QHp6PgAemhT0gsDGqHQGCkeBW602ZAARHtVK1aopsTjbm1isSYNiIICoAT2tiuAA6ZkwgBU8MGwykMwqeLpdUpfOB2IA3KYBKTCVIqVALMKxZlKjT+R0qcr5T0YKzoX1eKchsoAEwMJETFHTUx4mzLVYbLaGGC7bL44GgjlnUzU5ofPxfX7-B3bL3vFVu06QmFw-Wmyao-AYu04oVkolJ50qilq70Zpks3jQ9n64aG7nimDJqWC9MaxWS9rSiv0hUVYNAlPS1u0mspbVAA)